# When highlighting underlined text with custom selection color, underline does not show

Tags: html, css, selection

I'm making a web page with a custom selection color.

```css
::selection {
    background-color:#00ffff;
}
```

But take a look at this scenario:

```css
p::after {
    content:"Try selecting the above elements. The underline is not preserved, but the italic is preserved."
}
::selection {
    background-color:#00ffff;
    text-decoration:auto;
}
```

```html
<u>Select me!</u>
<i>Select me!</i>
<p></p>
```

So, how do I make the underline preserved in selected text?

```
Update:
I'm using Chrome 92.0.4479.3 (canary build) on Microsoft Windows 10 Home.
Screenshot:
```

[image: A screenshot of it not working]

Comment: I don't understand the question, the underline is preserved in the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the background-color of the selection in rgba mode or hsla mode or even hex code with additional 2 digits for alpha value(any mode where you can set alpha values) and reduce the alpha value from 1. Alpha value of around 0.5 seemed suitable to me. Too high alpha value will hide the underline beneath the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using auto use inherit for text-decoration like so :

```css
::selection{
      background-color: #00f;
      text-decoration: inherit;
    }
```

This way it should inherit the text-decoration of the parent element.